# And operators usage of && and !== in java

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

This is my first time looking into java and I'm trying to make this statement work.

```
    [if {(a) && (b) && (c) && (d)}!==0] {a}{b}{c}{d}
```

Asssuming a b c d were all numbers other than zero they should print out in order. But they do not...

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It doesn't look like Java at all.

Comment: That ... would not be Java. At all.

Comment: I have this engineering program and it's done in java (I believe it's done in BBj). I wanted to change the formatting of a printed page and I'm able to do so by entering in some operators. I don't have any documentation but I was assuming I would be able to enter in some code to help me further format the output. For example: `[if {X2}!==0][if {X1}!==0]  Length {X1}, Width {X2}` If the two values were actual numbers other than zero they would print out as I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0 && d != 0){
 System.out.println(a+""+b+""+c+""+d);
}
```

In java, if statement must use a boolean(result of ture or false) condition, instead of NON-ZERO expression in C/C++/Shell